# where can i find time series data sets of Australian beer consumption?

Tags: data-request, time-series

Where can I find time series data sets of "Australian beer consumption" and the amount of carbon dioxide measured monthly in the Ankara capitol of Turkey (ANSO)?

Comment: Weird correlation ahead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google?

[50 years of Australian beer consumption](http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/Latestproducts/4307.0.55.001Main%20Features62013-14?opendocument&tabname=Summary&prodno=4307.0.55.001&issue=2013-14&num=&view=) - ([my source](http://qz.com/542231/beer-consumption-in-australia-is-falling-at-a-remarkable-pace/))

[image]

---

Google?

[Air Quality Index](http://aqicn.org/city/turkey/ic-anadolu/ankara/kecioren/) and [official data source](http://www.havaizleme.gov.tr/Default.ltr.aspx) from Turkish government.

[image]

Comment: @philshem
How can I download "ANSO" dataset from above link that you gave me???
Any help to aid me in achive "The amount of carbon dioxide measured monthly in the Ankara capitol of Turkey (ANSO) between the years 1994 and 2006" is greatly appreciated!!!